# JQuery Infinite Scroll & dynamically generated pages

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement Jquery Infinite Scroll ( https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll ). Is there an option to send data with the GET request that this plugin sends with every scroll end ajax request? 
The data that i need to load is dynamically generated and i need to know the last Id that was loaded. The plugin seems to rely on static pages like 2.html, 3.html etc. Pls advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/renatosaito/jscroller
The default action is POST but you can change that easily.